# Facing Issue while comparing xcom value to a static variable in airflow 2.3.4

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I have a use case wherein I need to extract the value using xcom_pull.

Version of Airflow : `2.3.4`

Composer version : `2.1.1`

```
live_fw_num="{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id='" + DAG_ID + "',task_ids='get_fw_of_month')[0][0] }}")
```

The output coming out is `1`. Images Attached

The first image shows the xcom tab value
[image]

The second image shows the value when extracted in a `live_fw_num` variable
[image]

Code :

```
today = datetime.date.today()
    
def function_1(table2,table3,live_fw_num):
    if live_fw_num == '1' : ####( Tried with Integer value as well)
        <do something>
    else:
        <do something else>
        

with dag: 
    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_fw_of_month',
        python_callable=get_data,
        op_kwargs={'sql': task_1_func(tb1=<some table name>,
                                          curr_dte=today,
                                        )
                   }
    )
    
    
    task_3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'task3',
        python_callable = function_1,
        op_kwargs={'table2': <table name >,
                   'table3': <table name >, 
                   'live_fw_num': "{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id='" + DAG_ID + "',task_ids='get_fw_of_month')[0][0] }}"
                   }

    )
    
    task_1 >> task_3
```

But when I am comparing this value to a static variable using `if-else` clause, it goes to `else`  consition instead of `if` condition , even though the output value of `live_fw_num` is `1`

Comment: try to print to see in the log what is the value of live_fw_num

Comment: The o/p is 1 . Attached the Image for reference

Comment: Can you share more code please ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your `DAG` and your code and it worked on my side :

The only difference, I mocked the `get_data` method used by the first task, to return `1` as `String`.

```py
import datetime
import logging

import airflow
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

from integration_ocd.config import settings

today = datetime.date.today()


def get_data():
    return '1'


def function_1(table2, table3, live_fw_num):
    if live_fw_num == '1':
        logging.info('############################################<do something>')
    else:
        logging.info('############################################<do something else>')


with airflow.DAG(
        'dag_test_xcom',
        default_args=your_default_dag_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_fw_of_month',
        python_callable=get_data
    )

    task_3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task3',
        python_callable=function_1,
        op_kwargs={
            'table2': 'table1',
            'table3': 'table2',
            'live_fw_num': "{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id='dag_test_xcom',task_ids='get_fw_of_month')[0][0] }}"
        }
    )

    task_1 >> task_3
```

Comment: @codninja0908 have you solved your issue ?